# MouseArea event is propagated to its parent sibling. Why?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

Here's a code snippet with current form of the code

```
Rectangle
{
    id: menu
    GridLayout
    {
        id: layout
        columns: 4
        rows: 3

        Repeater
        {
            model: ListModel {}
            ToolButton {}
        }
        Rectangle
        {
        x: -3
        y: -33
        width: menu.width - 2
        height: menu.height + 33
        border.color: "red"
        border.width: 3
        color: "blue"
        MouseArea
        {
            x: mapToItem(menu, -5, -35).x
            y: mapToItem(menu, -5, -35).y
            width: menu.width
            height: menu.height + 35
            hoverEnabled: true
            preventStealing: true
            onEntered:console.log("onEntered")
            onExited:console.log("onExited menu mous area")
        }
        }
    }
}
```

The `MouseArea` hover event is propagated down to the `ToolButtons` in the `layout`. I don't get why. Hence, the `onEntered` and `onExited` events do not work as expected, because `onExited` happen inside the `MouseArea` when the `ToolButtons` are **'hovered'** and tooltips are shown. In the end I need the `MouseArea` to be a bit wider and longer than its parent `Rectangle` so that once `onExited` is emitted the `menu` gets invisible. After the test with `Rectangle` is successfull it will make sense to make C++ type Polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `onExited` must emits when entering `ToolButton`. According to [MouseArea.exited()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#exited-signal):

```
Rectangle {
    width: 400; height: 400
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea1
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea2
        width: 100; height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
    }
}
```

> Moving the mouse into `mouseArea2` from `mouseArea1` will cause `mouseArea1` to emit the exited signal.

If you do not want the `exited` signal to be emitted,

> If instead you give the two MouseAreas a parent-child relationship, moving the mouse into `mouseArea2` from `mouseArea1` will not cause `mouseArea1` to emit exited. Instead, they will both be considered to be simultaneously hovered.

That is, place `ToolButton` (and all related components) within the `MouseArea`. For example,

```
Rectangle {
    id: menu

    Rectangle {
        //some properties
        MouseArea {
            hoverEnabled: true
            //some properties

            onEntered:console.log("onEntered")
            onExited:console.log("onExited menu mous area")

            GridLayout {
                id: layout
                Repeater {
                    ToolButton {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case the GridLayout is the mouseArea1. In the first example if I move cursor into mouseArea2 there will still be emissions onExited and onEntered inside the visual area of the mouseArea2 because toolbuttons which are part of the mouseArea1 get hovered. I don't get why. And mouseArea1 and mouseArea2 in this case are of the same size.